# Angular promise: How to make finally block execute after an promise in then resolve

Tags: angularjs, promise, finally

Here's the code to reproduce my problem:

```
function controller($scope, $http, $q, $timeout) {

  asyncCallNo1()
   .then(function(res) {
     console.log(res);

     asyncCallNo2()
       .then(function(res) {
         console.log(res);
       });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    console.log("Final block execute");
  });

  function asyncCallNo1() {
    return $http.get("file1.json")
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.data.value;
      });
  }

  function asyncCallNo2() {
    return $http.get("file2.json")
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.data.value;
      });
  }
```

}

And here's the plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/pqQPiPGQnljqkERNnO2o?p=preview

My final block's statements execute **before** the promise in then() resolved. 
What I want is my final block execute **after** the promise in then() resolved. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You forgot to `return` the inner promise from the `then` callback, so I can't be awaited.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it helps me a lot.